# How do I disable Kudu (SCM) for a stopped Azure Web App using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-webapps

How do I disable Kudu (SCM) for a stopped Azure Web App using the Az.Websites PowerShell module?

I tried this:

```bsh
$app = Get-AzWebApp -Name $appName
$app.ScmSiteAlsoStopped = $true
Set-AzWebApp -WebApp $app

$app = Get-AzWebApp -Name $appName
$app.ScmSiteAlsoStopped
```

But it returns False.

Comment: I had a quick look around but can't see anything obvious. One workaround would be to add access restrictions to a known IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that via `Az.Resources` module, try the command as below.

```
$app = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceName "<webapp name>"
$app.properties.ScmSiteAlsoStopped = $true
$app | Set-AzResource -Force
```

[image]